# How to get the output of javap in a text file

Tags: shell, command-line

in order to view the java bytecode, we use javap as given below,

```
javap -c abc.class
```

it displays the bytecode on the command line. How can i get the output of the javap -c abc.class which is displayed on the command line to a text file.

Comment: Just pipe it: `javap -c abc.class > nameOfTheFileYouWant.txt` (that's just standard shell stuff, nothing to do with Java)

Comment: @yshavit you are correct? :) thanks it is correct. how can i accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using linux/cygwin/windows commandline you can save the output like this:

```
javap -c abc.class > file.txt
```